# How to remove the output layer from a model (custom model) to perform transfer learning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning

#python code

```
base_model = keras.applications.Xception(
    weights='imagenet',  # Load weights pre-trained on ImageNet.
    input_shape=(150, 150, 3),
    include_top=False)
```

the above code has include_top=False to remove the output layer for keras inbuild model. But for my custom model how to remove the output (classification) layer to use it for transfer learning?

i tried to build a transfer learning model for machine fault diagnosis dataset using transformer model. I tried multiple google search which result in model.pop() function which can be used only for sequential model where as my model is non sequential.